# What is the android.intent.category.DEVELOPMENT_PREFERENCE category for?

Tags: android, android-intent

What is the purpose of the [`android.intent.category.DEVELOPMENT_PREFERENCE`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#CATEGORY_DEVELOPMENT_PREFERENCE) category for?

If an activity adds this category in its intent filter, where can it be started? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Categories are generally used by the system (or other apps) to find different kinds of Activity to do certain things. Like `android.intent.category.LAUNCHER` is used to find all of the Activities that can be shown on a launcher list.

From the docs:

"The categories, if supplied, must all be listed by the activity as categories it handles. That is, if you include the categories CATEGORY_LAUNCHER and CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE, then you will only resolve to components with an intent that lists both of those categories. Activities will very often need to support the CATEGORY_DEFAULT so that they can be found by Context.startActivity()."

So `android.intent.category.DEVELOPMENT_PREFERENCE` is used to indicate an Activity is used for preferences during development. Since it was in API 1, it might have been included for possible future uses, of which none have been found/defined/implemented.

Comment: So, it's a not-have-been-used category?

Comment: Yeah, it just another defined category that, to my knowledge, is yet to have any well defined uses yet. Kind of like how some methods in Android allow you to pass flags, even though there aren't any flags defined yet. The designers just reserved something for the future.